# $pull modifier equivalent in PHP driver?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I don't see any $pull modifier in PHP driver while javascript shell supports $pull.

```
{ $pull : { field : _value } }
```

Following PHP code denies that $pull modifier is not supported

```
array('$pull' => array('x' => 'y'));
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$pull does exist for php driver. The syntax is as below:

```
$db -> update(array('field' => 'value'), array('$pull' => array('field_array' => $value)));
```

$pull works only if the field is an array.

Comment: Praveen, I think the problem lies somewhere else then. I heavily use php mongodb and have used the above pull syntax many times. You could probably try reinstalling the php driver like given here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center . Could you paste here the exact error message you are getting

Comment: Thanks Ninja, i was doing some mistake i guess.. now it's working.